# How to edit category.php template so it will display all post of specific category?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a simple wordpres category post loop in category.php template like this :

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $postid = get_the_ID();?>
```

How to change post limit ? Because now i get only ten posts per category. I'm using one template for all categories. I'm new to wordpres and trying to make my first custom template :)

Answer (score 1):

To display all posts on a category template you have override its default display per posts which is 10. Please refer following code:

```
$args = array('posts_per_page' => -1);
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();
    /** Your code here **/
}
```

Displaying all the posts on a template is not a good practice, instead I will recommend to display 10 posts per page and show pagination.

Reference for Pagination: https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination

Answer (score 0):

You can change the number of post per page from the backend. Settings->Reading. There you can change it where it says: "Blog pages show at most".

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in your argument

```
'posts_per_page' => -1
```

then you are done.

One more thing: you can change the default setting from admin to something other than 10. Go to the WordPress admin - Settings - Reading. There is an option like "Blog pages show at most". Type there the number of posts you want as the default.

It will change the setting for all pages , but if you want to make this change only for tag page then in your case you can change the code in loop-tag.php file as following :

```
global $wp;
$s_array = array('posts_per_page' => -1); // Change to how many posts you want to display 
$new_query = array_merge( $s_array, (array)$wp->query_vars );
query_posts($new_query);
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) :  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();  ?>
<!-- Here I grab the image from the post with that tag -->  
<?php endwhile;  ?>
<?php wp_reset_query();?>
```